# Is there a decent tool for comparing/diffing two Java packages?

Tags: java, diff

I'm looking for a tool that will give me a high level view of which files are different between two fairly large Java packages. If I could then drill down into individual files then that would be good. I don't want to go file by file if possible.. any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Beyond compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) (and other diff tools) can do directory compares too ...

Answer (score 1):

If you're more interested in API differences than content differences, check out [JDiff](http://www.jdiff.org/).

For example the Google Guava project uses it to show changes between releases.  Here is the r06 release diff: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release06/javadoc/jdiff/changes.html

Answer (score 1):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org) is an excellent Windows standalone diff tool and I use it for almost all of my source files. It can navigate through folder structures (in your case, your Java packages).

If you do use version control, it integrates very well with TortoiseSVN (and perhaps others in the Tortoise family).

Comment: tried it and think it should be correct answer. does very nice package comparisn.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pkgdiff](http://lvc.github.com/pkgdiff/) tool to compare java archives:

```
pkgdiff A.jar B.jar
```

See [sample report](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/pkgdiff_reports/args4j/2.0.11_to_2.0.12/changes_report.html) for args4j.

See also [japi-compliance-checker](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker) for analysis of API changes in your java archives.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use Kompare on Linux. Just a diff GUI front end, that can diff directories recursively. I believe there are many others (I'm sure I've seen a list somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse works well. Just select the two different packages (hold the Ctrl key, click on a package, click again on the other package), right click on one of the selected packages, go to the 'Compare With...' submenu, select 'Compare With Each Other'.

Comment: how smart is it ? - does it ignore differences in the `package` line of the file, and differences in the `import` statements if they point to classes within the scope of the selected package.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/) to do this too. It is also helpful for doing code merges. It is not free (about 80 bucks I think) but well worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I always use eclipses team synchronize (for included cvs; this requires one revision checked in and another one disk) works same way with subclipse plugin for subversion.

If you are on windows and don't have the checked in a version control system you could use [winmerge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winmerge/)

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) worked both on *nix and windows.